# adding a disclaimer message before adding to cart an itme in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help to write a function to show a popup message when add to cart button clicked.
I have more than 2000 products, so I want its applying on specific category, not to all product.
the message need to have two buttons with yes or no option.
clicking on yes will add item to the card. clicking no will close popup message.

I used a plugin named "Woocommerce disclaimer for products" but its applying on all product, and I don't want spend $49 for this!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what we need. You can edit your question with details of the exact problem you are having, what you have tried to solve it and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Comment: There is an alternative for you mentioned product. Link: https://wpexperts.io/blog/adding-disclaimer-popup-to-woocommerce-products-made-easy/ for the free plugin but there is a twist it's applying the disclaimer to all products but you expected only for a specific category. But once installed this plugin you skim over it and find is they gave any hooks and add your custom function to filter for specific category only. If you like to glance over the code without installing here is the link: https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woo-product-disclaimer/#trunk

Answer (score 1):

You should just put a message on top of the add to cart button, tbh, modal popup are scary for users, you should avoid them.

On top of your add to cart button on a product page (single-product.php) you could write something like this:

```
<!-- if category 1 OR "||" if category 2 then do stuff -->
<?php if ( ( is_product_category( 'your_category_slug_1_goes_here' ) ) || is_product_category( 'your_category_slug_1_goes_here' ) ) : ?>
<!-- If product category is matching then do stuff -->
<p style="padding:15px;border-radius:8px;background-color:#F8D7DA;color:#721C24;">
<strong>Warning</strong>: This product contains <u>Nicotine</u>. <u>Nicotine</u> is an addictive chemical
</p>
<?php else: ?>
<!-- If product category isn't matching then do stuff -->
<p style="padding:15px;border-radius:8px;background-color:#E2E3E5;color:#084085;">
<strong>Information</strong>: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope that will help you! Not tested but should be working.

Comment: Thank you for reply,
actually most of my customers are too lazy to read a few lines content!
so I decided put the disclaimer to their eyes via popup! :))))